Average kinetic energy variation between molecules in liquid
Suppose I have an insulated container filled with a liquid such as water with a known average temperature, pressure, and volume such as 300 degrees Kelvin, the average pressure at sea level, and a liter of volume occupying a cubic container.
Given this information, how do we roughly and as simply as possible calculate (not measure) the average difference between the kinetic energy of a random pair of the molecules?

Use the Maxwell-Boltzman distribution.
